# git architecture for persistent branch that consistently rebases to head of master

Tags: git

I have a repo which supports two distinct deployments of nearly the same code.  There is a single commit which is effectively a patch on master to create the functionality of my feature branch:

```
A -- B -- C # master
           \
            D # feature
```

The vast majority of code will be applied to `master`, but `feature` will need it too, i.e. Commit "D" should always have the HEAD of `master` as its parent.  My first instinct was to rebase `feature` consistently but then I'd be changing history when I push my newly rebased feature, right?

```
## Breaks History For Other Developers!
A -- B -- C -- E # master
                \
                 D # feature
```

Now I'm at a loss.  My initial solution was to `cherry-pick` across, but that ended up with an incredibly dirty git history and missed commits when people forgot to put their commit on both places.

**Is a continuous `rebase` an acceptable choice in this instance?  If not, how could I achieve what I'm looking for?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a much cleaner solution to merge master into your feature branch each commit, this keeps a clean commit history with no history editing.

This also lets you maintain versions of your feature branch and not suffer from it being rebased while you are working on it, only performing the merge from master when you need to.

In short you can do this like so:

```
git checkout feature; git merge master
```

Comment: testing it out, this gives me, as expected, merge commits on both branches (the actual commit on `master` and the merge commit on `feature`).  Is that going to be impossible to avoid if I want to not rewrite history?  As it stands, this leaves me with the same number of commits as cherrypicking across, but now I have to add commit msgs

Comment: It looks like, if I keep the restriction of not changing history, this is the only way, BUT I don't really like it.  As mentioned, I end up with the same ugly commit history as when cherry-picking manually, which I was trying to avoid.  I think I'm asking git to do something it can't

Comment: @ABMagil Firstly, you can avoid the ugly commit history by only doing one merge per release, then if you usethe --squash option when you merge all the commits from master are squashed into one. Second, there are so e subytle but important differences from cherry picking, when you cherry pick the got repo holds two different versions of every commit you pick, however when you merge only one version of the commits exist in the repo they are just applied to both branches.